# Wordpress orderby meta values in array

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, customization

I'm trying to get sorted list of posts using `get_posts` by meta value and the order of meta value is given in array.

This is what I currently have.

```
$stores = get_posts(array(
  'post_type'   => 'stores',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'fields' => 'ids', // I only need the ID's of posts
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key' => 'state',
  'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

This returns the array of posts sorted by `meta_value` in ASCENDING alphabetical order.

I have an array of possible values for `'meta_key' => 'state'`, i.e. `array('State1', 'State2', 'State3')`

I want to set order so that all stores which has meta value `State1` appears first, then from `State2` and after that `State3`
I can't use order by numeric value and alphabetical value as state names are gonna be random.

I found one post [here](https://keesiemeijer.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/sort-posts-by-multiple-meta-values-and-or-meta-keys/), it is using `mera_query_orderby`. I can't find any documentation for this and tried it, but it's not working. It returns posts ordered by ID.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**

I added the `meta_query_orderby` filters in functions.php

And the updated code I used from EXAMPLE 2, is like:

```
$stores = get_posts(array(
  'post_type'   => 'stores',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key'   => 'state', // Custom field key.
      'value' => array("CState1", "AState2", "BState3")
    )
  ),
  'meta_query_orderby' => array(
    array(
      'key'   => 'state', // (required) Custom field key.
      'value' => array("CState1", "AState2", "BState3")
    )
  )
));
```

Comment: I have checked the link you provided and perform a test on my local system and it work fine with `post` post type. Can you please come up with the code you have modified with respect to the reference link so i can try to help you out.?

Comment: @MominIqbal I've added the code I used from example post. I used `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query`. I think that should not be the reason it isn't working.

Comment: Remove all letters - ```array('State1', 'State2', 'State3')``` to ```array(1, 2, 3)``` and then easy can order by them.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an array of possible values for `'meta_key' => 'state'`, i.e.
>   `array('State1', 'State2', 'State3')`

If you want to sort the posts by the meta value in the exact order as in the above array, you can use a custom `WP_Query` parameter (to set the meta/sort values) and the `posts_orderby` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) to customize the `ORDER BY` clause, and in that clause, you would be using the `FIELD()` function in MySQL.

**Step 1**

Add this code to your plugin or theme (if theme, you'd add the code to the theme functions file):

```php
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'posts_orderby_meta_value_list', 10, 2 );
function posts_orderby_meta_value_list( $orderby, $query ) {
    $key = 'meta_value_list';
    if ( $key === $query->get( 'orderby' ) &&
        ( $list = $query->get( $key ) ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $list = "'" . implode( wp_parse_list( $list ), "', '" ) . "'";
        return "FIELD( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, $list )";
    }

    return $orderby;
}
```

**Step 2**

When making your post queries, set the `orderby` to `meta_value_list` and add `meta_value_list` to the query parameters — if you're using `get_posts()`, make sure `suppress_filters` is set to `false`:

```php
$stores = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'        => 'stores',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'fields'           => 'ids', // get just the ID's of posts
    'meta_key'         => 'state',
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value_list',
    'meta_value_list'  => array( 'State1', 'State2', 'State3', '' ),
    'suppress_filters' => false,
) );
```

PS: I the added `''` to the array so that posts where the metadata is (`''`) (i.e. *exists* in the database, but the value is empty) would be placed at the *bottom* of the results.

*Tried and tested working, but note that the above solution is only for single `orderby`, which means array is not supported.*

Comment: Thanks for pointing my attention to `suppress_filters`. The link I shared was working too, just I didn't add `suppress_filters` to the `get_posts` args. I didn't test your code though, thanks for the help.

Comment: BTW for other references, when you say solution is for single `orderby`, you mean single value and we can't use this method with multiple `meta_fields` (array), right?

Comment: You can, but the `orderby` can't be an array, or that the solution doesn't (although it could be made to) work with that array. I.e. `'orderby' => [ 'meta_value_list' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC' ]` for example, is not supported by the solution. Do try the solution (for single `orderby` as in the question), though..

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. There was an issue though, mentioned [here] (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329972/im-getting-call-to-undefined-function-wp-parse-list-out-of-the-blue). And I added the function in functions.php and it worked fine. Could be caching issue.

Comment: (I've deleted my previous comments) The `wp_parse_list` function is only available since WP 5.1.0. To make it work on earlier version, you can copy the function source [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_list/) and put it in your functions file - `if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_parse_list' ) ) { function wp_parse_list( $list ) { ... } }`

Comment: Is this still working? It doesn't seem to be applying to ACF fields

Comment: @user2521295 I suggest you to post your own question and provide as much details as possible. But yes, the solution in this answer should still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Display posts of type 'stores', ordered by 'state', and filtered to show only states.*/
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'stores',
    'meta_key'   => 'state',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'state',
            'value'   => array( 'State1', 'State2', 'State3'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Please modify the code according to database tables

Comment: BTW your answer is based on numerical meta values, where in my question the values are alphabetical and order is specified in array

Comment: @AkashK. Please read this `reference`.
`https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query`

We can modify `wp_query` according to our requirement. We need to check database `key` and `values` into `wp_postmeta` table. We can modify query according to `key` like `state` and `values` that you want in `results`.

Comment: Also you can try this: 
`use meta key like a state 'meta_key' => 'state' and use array like array('State1', 'State2', 'State3', 'State5', 'State6')`

Comment: `Apply the filter like add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'custom_states_order');
function custom_states_order( $orderby, $query ) {  //orderby meta code here }`